# Jolt transform array into multiple Objects

Tags: java, json, jolt

I am trying to transform the below JSON:

**Input:**

```json
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "end": "2023-01-27T09:19:29.849298Z",
      "id": "1",
      "start": "2023-01-27T09:18:24.59325Z",
      "name": "foo"
    },
    {
      "end": "2023-01-28T09:19:29.849298Z",
      "id": "2",
      "start": "2023-01-28T09:18:24.59325Z",
      "name": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "end": "2023-01-27T09:19:29.849298Z",
      "id": "1",
      "name": "foo",
      "start": "2023-01-27T09:18:24.59325Z"
    },
    {
      "end": "2023-01-28T09:19:29.849298Z",
      "id": "2",
      "name": "bar",
      "start": "2023-01-28T09:18:24.59325Z"
    }
  ],
  "date": [
    {
      "name": "startDate",
      "value": "2023-01-27T09:18:24.59325Z" //steps[0].start
    },
    {
      "name": "endDate",
      "value": "2023-01-27T09:19:29.849298Z" //steps[0].end
    }
  ]
}
```

I **tried** using the below spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "steps": {
        "*": "steps[]",
        "0": {
          "#startDate": "date[0].name",
          "start": "date[0].value",
          "end": "date[1].value",
          "#endDate": "date[1].name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But **`"*": "steps[]"`** only transforms the last element of the array steps. Please guide me as to what is wrong with the above spec, as I am new to jolt. Also, any pointers to the correct operations needed to achieve the above output will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&1",
        "0": {
          "#startDate": "date[0].name",
          "start": "date[0].value",
          "#endDate": "date[1].name",
          "end": "date[1].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can use `@` to get the `steps` array and put it into the `steps` key with `&1`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to conditionally pick by the existing(`steps`) array's indexes  while walking through it such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "steps": {
        "@1": "",// derive the whole value from the upper level, eg. replicate it  
        "0": {// the first index
          "#startDate": "date[&1].name",
          "start": "date[&1].value"
        },
        "*": {// the other index(this case there's only one)
          "#endDate": "date[&1].name",// bring the value of the wrapper object'S index by using &1(going up one level the tree) 
          "end": "date[&1].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]